# Compresing View

Tags: iphone

in "iPhone tips" app when u scroll view from right to left,thay have show view being comppresed.It gives the effect like when u will open pages in book.Like when u go go next next page in a note book.How to achive this.Including the fonts in page will also get compressed.How to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use Affine transforms to achieve what you want, theres no (documented) functionallity to do that transitions so you are going to have to create it on your own.

Comment: what kind of affine transform do i need to use.Even the fonts size should be also decresed.

Comment: dont know, it is probably a mix of things